# SELECT rows with same id using different id as condition?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have the following table:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| id | link_id[FK] | category_id[FK] | parent_id[FK] | sort_order |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| 1       2             1                 1               1       |
| 2       2             133               1               2       |
| 3       3             2                 2               1       |
| 4       3             200               2               2       |
| 5       3             333               200             3       |
| 6       4             1                 1               1       |
| 7       5             3                 3               1       |
| 8       5             133               3               2       |
| 9       5             223               133             3       |
| 10      5             456               223             4       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to be able to `SELECT` all rows with the same `link_id`, but using the `category_id` as the condition. So here is the example result I am looking for.

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| id | link_id[FK] | category_id[FK] | parent_id[FK] | sort_order |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| 1       2             1                 1               1       |
| 2       2             133               1               2       |
| 7       5             3                 3               1       |
| 8       5             133               3               2       |
| 9       5             223               133             3       |
| 10      5             456               223             4       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've tried this query, but it only returns the rows that equal `category_id` 133.

```
SELECT *
FROM table a
WHERE (a.object_id,a.category_id) IN (
    SELECT b.link_id,b.link_id
    FROM table b
    WHERE b.category_id = 133
    AND a.link_id = b.link_id

) ORDER BY a.sort_order
```

I've also tried a SELF JOIN, which is basically what I need, but then I get separate columns and I need them combined like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to get the `link_id`s from the table where `category_id = 133`, then query the table for all the rows with that `link_id`.

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE link_id IN (
    SELECT link_id FROM `table`
    WHERE category_id = 133
)
ORDER BY link_id, sort_order
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67eb4/5

You should also be able to do this with a "self join", too:

```
SELECT a.* FROM `table` a
JOIN `table` b ON a.link_id = b.link_id
WHERE b.category_id = 133
ORDER BY a.link_id, a.sort_order
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67eb4/6

Comment: Thanks Rocket, it works perfectly. Can u tell me how to specify two `category_id's`? Say 1 and 133?

Comment: Nevermind, figured out that I can do a second `WHERE` condition with the second `category_id` for the first query.

Comment: `WHERE category_id IN (1, 133)`?

Comment: Would be nice if that worked, but it gets all rows with one id or the other.